# Apache Nifi : How to create parquet file from CSV file with schema saved in "avro.schema" attribute

Tags: csv, apache-nifi, parquet

I am trying to create a parquet file from a CSV file using Apache Nifi.

I am able to convert the CSV to parquet file, but the problem is, the schema of the parquet file contains struct type(Which I need to overcome) and convert it into string type.

I am using Apache Nifi 1.14.0 on Windows Server 2016.

This is what I've tried to convert CSV to parquet till now...

**I have used the below 3 controllers**

1. CSVReader
2. CSVRecordSetWriter
3. ParquetRecordSetWriter

**And, These are the processors/Flow**

1. GetFile
2. ConvertRecord(CSVReader to CSVRecordSetWriter and this will automatically generate "avro.schema" attribute and in next step I am updating this attribute)
3. UpdateAttribute(Updating "avro.schema" attribute, where ever I've got 2 data types inferred, I am replacing it to '["null","string"]')
4. ConvertRecord(CSVReader to ParquetRecordSetWriter)
5. UpdatedAttribute(For appending '.parquet' in the filename)
6. PutFile

I also want to know, how to view a .parquet file in Windows OS. Currently, I am reading the parquet file via PySpark and checking the schema. :|

This is how parquet file schema looks like after conversion. I want **string** instead of **Struct** as output.

[image]

Please Note: There are lots of CSVs with many columns/fields. I don't want to create schema manually.

OR
Any other ways to achieve this would be very helpfull.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with some more options of "**ParquetRecordSetWriter**", I was able to create a parquet file with the schema that I've captured in "**avro.schema**" attribute.

[image]